# Step up converter with MC34063

Tags: voltage-regulator, step-up, mc34063

I have a 24v humidifier that I would like to power using a 12v power supply, so in order to do that, I designed a voltage step up regulator based on the MC34063. But since the humidifier requires a current of about 1A to work, it seens that my calculations led to really big and beefy components in order to make it work and at this point I'm not exactly sure if the ic will be able to handle all the current flowing trough it. So I would like some opinions on that.

[image: Circuit diagram]

For the calculations I considered a switching frequency of 90KHz, a desired output of 24V 1A (max), minimum input voltage of 12V and a output Vrippple(pp) of 20mV.

Answer (score 1):

For a boost converter providing 24V at 1A from a 12V supply, the circuit will need to handle at least 2A, and the switch will have to handle more than that, depending on duty cycle. So you should use an external switching transistor as shown in the data sheet:

[image: MC34063 Boost Circuit]

Comment: I think I understood, but I have two more questions. Would it be better to design the circuit to handle about 2.8A (I’m considering this value based on a 70% efficiency of the ic)?Also, by designing my circuit to handle that current, it would mean that my transistor, inductor and also diode must handle that current?

Comment: The datasheet should provide guidelines and calculations. The critical component is the inductor. It must not saturate on current peaks with some amount of DC current as well (if running continuous mode). I would use LTSpice to simulate it.